# How to Set Up the Gmail Mailer in WP Mail SMTP

Tags: wordpress, email, smtp, gmail

Got real life feedback from users on my weblog that they couldn't send emails anymore even though this was working.

I'm using WP Mail SMTP with Gmail, which was previously configured.

After going to the admin panel, under WP Mail SMTP > Email Test:

> You cannot send an email. Mailer is not properly configured. Please
>   check your settings.

[image: WP Mail SMTP with Gmail]

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This link](https://wpmailsmtp.com/docs/how-to-set-up-the-gmail-mailer-in-wp-mail-smtp/) has everything we need to know about this configuration.

In order to fix this problem I just followed the next two steps

1. [Create a Web App in Your Google Account](https://wpmailsmtp.com/docs/how-to-set-up-the-gmail-mailer-in-wp-mail-smtp/#create-app)
2. [Grant Permissions and Send Test Email](https://wpmailsmtp.com/docs/how-to-set-up-the-gmail-mailer-in-wp-mail-smtp/#permissions)

The tricky part is somewhere in step 2 where we are going to get a login screen for Google. Once logging in, I got a not secure page

[image: Not secure]

had to click advanced

[image: Advanced not secure]

and click *Go to tiagoperes.eu unsafe*.

Only then was able to see a screen asking for permission for this site to send email on my behalf.

Then, under WP Mail SMTP > Email Test:

[image: Button is now green]

Once clicking it, received the email so the problem is solved.

[image: Email sent]